# Merge two SQL Server Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to merge these two queries?

i)

```
SELECT 
      runId,
      Runs.prodId,
      prodDate,
      prodName,
      buildNumber,
      totalCount as TotalTestCases,
      (passCount*100)/(passCount+failCount) as PassPercent, 
      passCount,
      failCount,
      runOwner 
FROM Runs,Product 
WHERE Runs.prodId=Product.prodId
```

ii)

```
SELECT (CAST(counts.Count as decimal(10,4)) / CAST(failCount as decimal(10,4))) as PercentAnalysed
FROM Runs 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS 'Count', 
    runId
 FROM Results WHERE Analysed = 'True' GROUP BY runId 
)counts on counts.runId = Runs.runId
```

I tried this :

```
SELECT 
      Runs.runId,
      Runs.prodId,
      prodDate,prodName,
      buildNumber,
      totalCount as TotalTestCases,
      (passCount*100)/(passCount+failCount) as PassPercent, 
      passCount,
      failCount,
      runOwner,
      counts.runId,
      (cast(counts.Count as decimal(10,4)) / cast(failCount as decimal(10,4))) as PercentAnalysed 
FROM Runs,Product 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', 
    runId 
 FROM Results WHERE Analysed = 'True' GROUP BY runId 
) counts on counts.runId = Runs.runId
WHERE Runs.prodId=Product.prodId
```

but it gives an error.

Individually, both the queries run fine. Also,the number of rows returned by both of the queries are the same, so that isn't the issue.

The error is:

> "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 The multi-part identifier
>   "Runs.runId" could not be bound."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Inner Join` to join Runs and Products table.

```
select Runs.runId,
Runs.prodId,
prodDate,
prodName,
buildNumber,
totalCount as TotalTestCases,
(passCount*100)/(passCount+failCount) as PassPercent, 
passCount,
failCount,
runOwner,
counts.runId,
(cast(counts.Count as decimal(10,4)) / cast(failCount as decimal(10,4))) as PercentAnalysed 
from 
Runs AS Runs Inner Join Product AS Product On Runs.prodId=Product.prodId
left join 
( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', runId FROM Results WHERE Analysed = 'True' GROUP BY runId 
) counts on counts.runId = Runs.runId
```

Answer (score 0):

if your two first queries are working properly then you can use both of them in a query like below and it should word properly (you just need to have a join condition)

```
select * from --select columns you want
-- Query i
(
  select runId,Runs.prodId,prodDate,prodName,buildNumber,totalCount as
    TotalTestCases,(passCount*100)/(passCount+failCount) as PassPercent, 
    passCount,failCount,runOwner from Runs,Product where 
    Runs.prodId=Product.prodId
) qi --you need to have a join column inside it i.e runId
join
-- Query ii
(
select runId , (cast(counts.Count as decimal(10,4)) / cast(failCount as decimal(10,4))) as PercentAnalysed
from Runs 
left join ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', runId FROM Results WHERE Analysed = 'True' GROUP BY runId ) counts on counts.runId = Runs.runId
) qii --you need to have a join column inside it. i.e runId

on qi.runId=qii.runId
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix where and join statements. That doesn't work:

```
select Runs.runId,Runs.prodId,prodDate,prodName,buildNumber,
    totalCount as TotalTestCases,(passCount*100)/(passCount+failCount) as PassPercent, passCount,failCount,runOwner,
    counts.runId,(cast(counts.Count as decimal(10,4)) / cast(failCount as decimal(10,4))) as PercentAnalysed 
from Runs join Product  on Runs.runId= Product.prodId
left join ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count', runId FROM Results WHERE Analysed = 'True' GROUP BY runId ) counts on counts.runId = Runs.runId
```

When you use join in from statement you have to use join for every table.

Comment: Your query gives an error.
The multi-part identifier "counts.runId" could not be bound.

The multi-part identifier "counts.Count" could not be bound.

Comment: You have missed the inner query :(SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS 'Count', 
    runId
 FROM Results WHERE Analysed = 'True' GROUP BY runId 
)counts

Comment: @bishnu No the query is there.